# Unsupported media type on postman POST call for SpringBoot REST API in terminal

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, cmd, postman

I have built a basic SpringBoot REST API, and when I try to add players using POSTMAN I am getting the following error in the CMD:

```
curl -X POST "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/players -d '{"firstName": "Magnus", "lastName": "Carlsen", "email": "magnuscarlsen@gmail.com"}'
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
{"timestamp":"2021-11-03T16:31:33.626+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/players"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Magnus,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: lastName
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Carlsen,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: email
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 24
```

If I just do:

```
curl localhost:8080/players
```

I get back an empty JSON object so that works correctly.

Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/players")
public class PlayersController {

    private final PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    public PlayersController(PlayerRepository playerRepository) {
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Player> getClients() {
        return playerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Player getPlayer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return playerRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity createPlayer(@RequestBody Player player) throws URISyntaxException {
        Player savedPlayer = playerRepository.save(player);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/players/" + savedPlayer.getId())).body(savedPlayer);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity updatePlayer(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Player player) {
        Player currentPlayer = playerRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
        currentPlayer.setFirstName(player.getFirstName());
        currentPlayer.setFirstName(player.getLastName());
        currentPlayer.setEmail(player.getEmail());
        currentPlayer = playerRepository.save(player);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(currentPlayer);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deletePlayer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        playerRepository.deleteById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

I have looked online for this forbidden media type error but every solution is using some kind of program not just in the terminal CMD so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You should provide your Controller method here. Have you annotated the method with e.g. `@PostMapping(value="/players",  consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")`?

Comment: As @TheFrozenOne already mentioned, please provide your Controller code, otherwise we can't help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TheFrozenOne Hello, I have added the controller and there doesn't seem to be the annotation you have just mentioned, is this essential? I was following a tutorial.

Comment: Check out all the errors. Curl is taking bits of your JSON body as separate arguments. Your escaping must be off.

Comment: Ok, your curl statement is not correct (try to swap single and double quotes!), but the request is being sent, otherwise you wouldn't receive a HTTP response code. So try to annotate your method with
`@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")` and check if the response code changes with the curl statement 
`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/players -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{'firstName': 'Magnus', 'lastName': 'Carlsen', 'email': 'magnuscarlsen@gmail.com'}"`.

Comment: @TheFrozenOne Thanks for your help, but even when I added the PostMapping annotation and used your curl statement I am now getting: {"timestamp":"2021-11-04T15:31:34.909+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/players"}

Comment: Ok, but that's sth different. Bad request (400) means that your request body has the wrong format, so the media type seems to be ok. So you might also show the Player class. The other potential error source is the single quotes in the request, so you can try with escaped double quotes:
`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/players -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"firstName\": \"Magnus\", \"lastName\": \"Carlsen\", \"email\": \"magnuscarlsen@gmail.com\"}"`

Comment: @JoeBailey can you add to your question the stack trace you get in your application for when you get the 400 error? Thanks!

Comment: @TheFrozenOne Thanks a lot! The escaped double quotes worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your curl command is not right. Try the following:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/players -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"firstName": "Magnus", "lastName": "Carlsen", "email": "magnuscarlsen@gmail.com"}'
```